Gstreamer pipeline to capure video and audio to stream it simultaneously over RTSP
I have to develop the Gstreamer pipeline, my existing pipeline which captures and stream data is as below,
"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! vpuenc_h264 bitrate=1500 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96"

I have to modify this pipeline to include below,

Use dummy audio file to get the audio
process and stream video and audio simultaneously

I have tried several pipelines but they are not working. Please provide the pipeline which can do this task.

So with test-launch example, you can keep adding the streams with names pay0, pay1, pay2 ... etc and the example will publish all the streams on the same url /test. So you can add audio stream with something like
test-launch "( v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! vpuenc_h264 bitrate=1500 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue ! opusenc ! rtpopuspay name=pay0 pt=97 )"

